# List of all FIR and their authorities

Tags: icao

Wikipedia has this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_region containing a table of all FIR (with ICAO codes) and their respective authority countries.

Is there any place where I can download an updated list like this one as a CSV file (or XML)?

I need to do some automatic calculation of overflight costs. For that I have a set of calculation formulas from IATA, but they are based on authority country, and my input is based on the FIR, that the actual flight is passing through. Therefore I need some way to find the authority country for each specific FIR.

I would prefer somehow to be able to automatically download a fresh list once in a while. I'm not yet sure, how often these data might change.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! You might get a better answer if you can tell us what you need the data for and how reliable you need it to be. For example, the Wikipedia page you linked to has 310 FIRs, but [ICAO's own list](https://www.icao.int/safety/FITS/Lists/Current%20FIR%20Status/FPL%20Status.aspx) has 405. Also, do you need updates when the list changes? As a general comment, the best way to get high-quality and up-to-date aviation data is usually to pay for it.

Comment: Valid point @Pondlife, I've updated my OP.

Comment: Such data is not freely available

Comment: @J.Hougaard Please read my own answer to the OP. I believe it is freely available.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and answering your own question when you found the answer. Unfortunately resource location questions are specifically [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here

Comment: Just read the scope defining this exchange area. I would argue, that my question falls into the category "Aviation Regulations".

Comment: @CarstenGehling *"Is there any place where I can download an updated list like this one as a CSV file (or XML)?"* is a resource request. What I linked to includes what is off topic, and includes resource location with the specific example *" Where can I get a feed of flight-related data?"*. Again, please stick around, it's good to have new users, but this particular question is specifically off topic.

Comment: @Jamiec Fair enough :-) Should I delete the OP then?

Comment: @CarstenGehling no need, unless you really want to

Comment: *Should* be on-topic, IMO.

Comment: @pericynthion - The problem is the site will then become a shopping site with companies promoting their non-free APIs and what not. Resource/shopping questions are all off-topic across all SE sites I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, I found what I needed here: https://www.icao.int/safety/istars/pages/api-data-service.aspx

They currently have 58 datasets. The one satisfying my needs is **"Flight Information Regions - Names"**.

When registering for an API key, I am allowed to do 100 requests for free each month. Downloading the entire list counts as 1 request. So the way I read it, I am complying with their EULA. If I'm wrong, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the table contents, then Copy, paste into Excel, select Save As, then Save A Type: CSV or XML.

You'll be asked to confirm you want that vs the standard Excel format.

Comment: Good solution but what if wikipedia is not updated?

Comment: It's definitely outdated. e.g. Sondrestrom FIR is now called Nuuk FIR.